# Can i send bitcoin from one address in wallet with multiple addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, wallet.dat, sweep

I have a btc backup wallet.dat file. I dumped the file with pywallet.py using python. I now have the wallet.txt showing all my addresses (Legacy) with their private keys in that wallet. So there are multiple addresses each with amounts of btc in them. Can i sweep or send btc from the addresses individually to another address/wallet like electrum? And will the rest if the addresses still be in my wallet then with their btc balances? How do i do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> **Can i sweep or send btc from the addresses individually to another address/wallet like electrum?**

Yes, but you sweep the private keys not the addresses.

> **How do i do this exactly?**

By following published guidance, such as that given on the Electrum unofficial guide:

See [Electrum - sweeping private keys](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/sweeping-your-private-keys-into-electrum/#:%7E:text=Sweeping%20your%20private%20keys%20means,will%20cost%20you%20transaction%20fees.)

> - To sweep your private keys you go to Wallet menu > Private keys > Sweep:
> - Then you enter your private keys one per line:
> - Your private keys need to be in Wallet Import Format (WIF) or mini private key format. These are standard formats for private keys.

Comment: Ok great thank you. Just to be clear, can i sweep the private keys individually as my wallet holds more than one address with their priv keys. Will my wallet be compromised if i sweep them individually?

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't sweep one key at a time. The most prudent method would be to make backups of the wallets before sweeping and test recovery from the backups on separate devices.